# Disable menu item based on selected window on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have two windows and I want to be able to disable menu items based on which window is selected and based on its state.

Here is some example code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WindowMenuApp: App
{
    @State var disabledMenu: Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene
    {
        WindowGroup
        {
            ContentView(disabledMenu: $disabledMenu)
        }
        .commands
        {
            CommandGroup(after: .newItem , addition:{ Button ("Save Window...")
                {
                    // command
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("S", modifiers: [.command])
                .disabled(disabledMenu)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var text: String = ""
    @Binding var disabledMenu: Bool
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            TextField("text", text: $text)
                .onChange(of: text)
            { new in
                disabledMenu = new == "1"
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear()
        {
            disabledMenu = text == "1"
        }
    }
    
 }
```

How to reproduce:

- Create two new windows.
- Type in "1" into one of the window's text
  field. This will disable the menu item of the first window
- Click on the second window. The menu item will still be disabled.

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't have much (basically none) experience with windows but you could maybe have an environment object that tracks which window is active. You could set the value of this environment object using window life cycle event callbacks. UIKit has something like "didResignActive" and an equivalent for when it becomes active. SwiftUI should have similar features (could be features of `Scene`). Hope this helped in some way!